# 6502 assembly JMP

Tags: assembly, 6502

If I use this opcode

```
JMP
Jump to New Location

(PC+1) -> PCL
(PC+2) -> PCH
N   Z   C   I   D   V
-   -   -   -   -   -
addressing  assembler   opc bytes   cycles
absolute    JMP oper    4C  3   3
```

and give it a hex value of say 0x0604 will it jump to that location execute what's there and then continue until it gets back to the JMP statement, or will it execute whats at 0x0604 and then do the next instruction after the JMP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `JMP $0604` instruction will change the program counter to the value `$0604` and then start executing the instructions starting at address `$0604`. It will not return back to the instruction after the `JMP`. To accomplish that you need to change the `JMP` to a `JSR`, and make sure the subroutine code at `$604` has an `RTS` instruction to return from  the subroutine.

Comment: So it would infinitely loop?

Comment: Only if the JMP instruction is located at address 0604. Then you'd have a JMP instruction jumping to itself.

Comment: I was thinking about that in a pretty dense way I understand now. thank you